# Why aren't load() and beforeload() called?

Tags: javascript, cordova, touch, extjs

Sencha Touch 2:

This is my store definition

```
var incidentsJson = loadJson();

Ext.define("App.store.EventsFeed", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],

    config: {
            listeners: {
                    beforeload: function() {
                            console.log('before store load');
                            return true;
                    },
                    load: function(store, records) {
                            console.log(' store loaded', records);

                    }
            },
            model: 'App.model.Incident',
            autoLoad: true,
            data: incidentsJson,
            reader: {
                    type: 'json',
            }
    }
});
```

The data is loaded but `load()` and `beforeload()` don`t get called, what's going on?

Comment: Don't know why, but apparently the store only calls `load()` and `beforeload()` only if you load your data through the proxy property...

Answer (score 0):

The beforeload has to be outside "config".

Example:

```
  var incidentsJson = loadJson();

Ext.define("App.store.EventsFeed", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],

    listeners: {
          beforeload: function() {
               console.log('before store load');
                return true;
           },
           load: function(store, records) {
                console.log(' store loaded', records);
           }
     },

    config: {
            model: 'App.model.Incident',
            autoLoad: true,
            data: incidentsJson,
            reader: {
                    type: 'json',
            }
    }
});
```